# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php

I keep getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in H:\USBWebserver\root\GIPSite\stagetoevoegen.php on line 46

After a lot of research and tried many possible solutions, it still gives the error
Here is the code

```
if (isset($_POST['cmdVerstuur']))
        {
            $invoegen=$link->prepare("insert into tblstagebedrijven (Naam,Begeleider, Locatie, Telefoon, E-mail, Opmerking) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $naam = $_POST['txtNaambedrijf'];
            $begeleider = $_POST['txtBegeleider'];
            $locatie = $_POST['txtLocatie'];
            $telefoon = $_POST['txtTelefoon'];
            $email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
            $opmerking = $_POST['txtOpmerking'];
            $invoegen->bind_param('ssssss', $naam, $begeleider, $locatie, $telefoon, $email, $opmerking);
            $resultaat=$invoegen->execute();

                if($resultaat)
                    echo "Het stagebedrijf is toegevoegd";
                else
                    echo "Er is een fout opgetreden";

            $link->close();

        }
```

I have a connection.php file that is included and other pages do work with it.

Comment: Have you checked the error message?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Sidenote: Wrap your `E-mail` in backticks in your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that actually wrapping `E-mail` in `backticks` will solve his query problem, and fix his issue

Comment: It actually doesn't fix it, I tried but still get the same error and i don't get how to do that pdo.error.php thingy

Comment: pdo.error.php thingy? Your code is not PDO, it's mysqli since you're using `bind_param`. Is your DB connection mysqli or PDO?

Comment: if wrapping `E-mail` didn't solve your issue, then you have a typo in your query maybe wrong table name or wrong column name... Double check your query.

Comment: Please go over my (edited) answer below. @user3570101

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I tested your code and was successful (*in conjunction with my answer*).
See my troubleshooting-debugging notes below.

Taking out the backticks around the `E-mail` column gave the following error message similar to this and using error reporting such as:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

at the top under the opening `<?php` tag

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-mail, Opmerking) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1' in /home/user/public_html/dbtest1.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/public_html/dbtest1.php(17): mysqli->prepare('insert into tbl...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/user/public_html/dbtest1.php on line 17

---

#### Original answer before edit:

Wrap your `E-mail` column value in backticks or choose another way, `Email` or `E_mail`

```
(Naam,Begeleider, Locatie, Telefoon, `E-mail`, Opmerking)
```

You can use punctuation, white space, international characters, and SQL reserved words if you use delimited identifiers.

I quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008966/): (which I already knew)

> *The major reason against use of hyphen is that most references must then quote the field names. Otherwise they will look like a subtraction operator, both to MySQL and humans.*

Using error reporting would have caught that.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://www.php.net/mysqli_error

Example:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

---

Error checking methods (MySQL-PDO)

MySQL

```
// connect (create a new MySQLi object) with custom predefined constants
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE_NAME);

// $mysqli->connect_error is buggy until PHP 5.3.0
if (mysqli_connect_error())
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if (!$result)
{
    throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
}

while($row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // your result handling code (print it)
}
```

PDO

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

---

**Footnotes:** (troubleshooting-debugging)

Place `var_dump($link->error);` before `$invoegen->bind_param('ssssss'`

a) You can also try this method:

```
$invoegen = $mysqli->prepare("...");

    if( $invoegen !== FALSE ) {
        $invoegen->bind_param(...);
        $invoegen->execute();
    }
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

  b) Check to see what your column types are.

  c) Place `var_dump($invoegen);` right after your prepare call.

  d) Check your column names for spelling and/or actual existence.

  e) Check to see if your form elements are named and with no typos, checking for letter-case also. `A!=a;` meaning that an uppercase `A` is not treated the same as `a`. For example: `name="Animal"` as opposed to `name="animal"` *those are two different animals altogether.*

---

**The code I used to test it with:** - All columns set to `VARCHAR(255)`

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

    $invoegen=$link->prepare("insert into tblstagebedrijven (Naam,Begeleider, Locatie, Telefoon, `E-mail`, Opmerking) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    /*
    $naam = $_POST['txtNaambedrijf'];
    $begeleider = $_POST['txtBegeleider'];
    $locatie = $_POST['txtLocatie'];
    $telefoon = $_POST['txtTelefoon'];
    $email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $opmerking = $_POST['txtOpmerking'];
    */

    $naam = "Fred";
    $begeleider = "txtBegeleider";
    $locatie = "txtLocatie";
    $telefoon = "txtTelefoon";
    $email = "txtEmail";
    $opmerking = "txtOpmerking";

    $invoegen->bind_param('ssssss', $naam, $begeleider, $locatie, $telefoon, $email, $opmerking);
    $resultaat=$invoegen->execute();

        if($resultaat)
            echo "Het stagebedrijf is toegevoegd - OK";
        else
            echo "Er is een fout opgetreden - NOT ok";

    $link->close();
```

Comment: Renaming the column is obviously better than using backticks.

Comment: That's a good point, I will edit to reflect that. @Sherlock thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
... n, E-mail, Opmerking) v...
        ^---- seen as a mathematical subtraction operation
```

You need to quote it:

```
... n, `E-mail`, Opmerking) v...
```

Plus, if you'd had proper error handling in your code, you'd have been told that your prepare operation failed and returned a boolean false:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare(...);
if (!$stmt) {
   die($link->errorInfo); // or whatever your DB lib's error reporting method is
}
```