# Mysql Where Calculate

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT id as bid,sku,product_name,
       (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM sales WHERE uid = bid) as tsa,
       (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM buying WHERE uid = bid) as taa 
FROM product WHERE ?
```

I wanna where `taa - tsa if 0` show query Help please I need subtraction

I'm using `WHERE taa-tsa = 0` but dont work

I solved with having thanks

Comment: *"I'm using WHERE taa-tsa = 0"* well that hyphen is a problem. Checking for errors would have told you about the (off-topic) syntax error.

Comment: use `CASE` in mysql. i think you are looking for that.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju look at their column name `taa-tsa` ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008953/is-there-any-good-reasons-that-i-should-not-use-dash-in-field-names-in-mysql

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think in this case the `-` is a minus not a column name

Comment: Unknown column 'taa' in 'where clause' always

Comment: @RiggsFolly *"I'm using `WHERE taa-tsa = 0` but dont work"* - that should have been rephrased ;-) looks like a query to me. and this too `FROM product WHERE ?` are they asking us what to do for them?

Comment: Are you actually using the `?` as a parameter substitution i.e. you are using `bind_param` on that

Comment: voted to close as unclear

Comment: who know how can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the output of a SELECT query based on the contents of an aggregate value, then you need to specify the filter in a HAVING clause (there WHERE clause filters the input rows).

Hence either:

```
SELECT id as bid,sku,product_name,
   (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM sales WHERE uid = bid) as tsa,
   (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM buying WHERE uid = bid) as taa 
FROM product
HAVING tsa=taa
```

or

```
SELECT ilv.*
FROM (
   SELECT id as bid,sku,product_name,
   (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM sales WHERE uid = bid) as tsa,
   (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM buying WHERE uid = bid) as taa 
   FROM product
) as ilv
WHERE tsa=taa
```

Your query is very badly constructed. Its impossible to tell what the query should look like without knowing a lot more about the structure of the data, the database, and the usage of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id as bid,sku,product_name,
           (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM sales WHERE uid = bid) as tsa,
           (SELECT SUM(piece) FROM buying WHERE uid = bid) as taa 
    FROM product
) as vw

WHERE (vw.taa - vw.tsa) = 0
```